# MacBook Air (2019) screen freeze after login

Tags: macos, screen

I logged in on my MacBook Air after a week or so and after the login it started to act a little laggy but worked normal. After a few hours, the screen froze and after a hard reboot screen looks like this:

[image]

If I log into my user in safe mode or recovery, everything is fine except everything is a bit slow. This might prove the problem is not hardware related (I think).

I have tried PRAM/NVRAM and SMC reset, none of them worked.

Comment: Can you boot with Verbose Mode (CMD+V during boot), take a slow-motion video of the boot console text with your iPhone, then upload the still-screens here so that we can examine the boot process (especially the end)?